# In landscape mode issue in samsung galaxy tab in android

Tags: android

In landscape mode `fill_parent` is not filling the background 1024 * 600 with a resolution, in android. 
Can anybody tell me what to do?

Thanks

Comment: please provide some code or tell us more about what u want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add support screen in android manfest file